# Unstrusted App Developer alert customisation

Tags: ios, certificate, alert, profile

[image]

Can I somehow edit text in quotes? So it would look like this:
Do you trust the developer "My Company Name" to run apps on your iPhone?
Without this "iPhone Developer: " or "iPhone Distribution: " parts?

Comment: just curious, when does that message appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible to amend/edit those `UIAlertControllers` or `UIAlertViews`. They are part of the standard iOS system and not part of your app.

Comment: I was thinking about some let's say - configuration files or other tricks to do this, not about editing alert directly :)

Comment: Again no this isn't possible. Anything outside of your app you can't touch. Your app works in a sandbox mode so doesn't know about anything outside of itself including these messages.